# How to save the highscore properly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, sklabelnode

Apologies if Ive already asked this, but Im having a very hard time.

I have an SKLabelNode set up like this:

```
    var label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Baveuse")
 class GameScene: SKScene {

  func pointsLabel() -> SKLabelNode {


    label.position = CGPointMake(-80, 500)
    label.fontSize = 50.0
    label.name = "points"
    label.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()

return label
  }
```

And incremented like this:

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        numPoints++
        label.text =  "\(numPoints)"


}
```

In a separate SKScene, I have it set up like so:

```
    let score = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Baveuse")

    score.fontSize = 70.0
    score.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    score.position = CGPointMake(size.width / 2, 500)
    score.text = "\(numPoints)"
    addChild(score)




  let highScore = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Baveuse")
    highScore.fontSize = 40.0
    highScore.fontColor = UIColor(red: 88.0/255.0, green: 148.0/255.0, blue:87.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        highScore.text = String(format: "Best: %d", numPoints)

   }
```

How would I make it so that it would take the highest score from numPoints and keep it stored until another high score was made? Will post mode code if necessary.

Comment: is this a serious question?  If you know how to make a variable to score, you should know how to make a variable for high score, and be able to set the high score when score is higher than it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` for this (as you´ve added a tag for). When a game ends add this `if-statement`.

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey("highScore") >= numPoints){
   // New highscore
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(numPoints, forKey: "highScore")
}
```

Here you check if the `numPoints` value is greater or equal (you have to check if you want to use equal) than the value in your `NSUserDefaults highscore` then you update the highscore.